# how to solve Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

I have created a function still showing **Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined**

test.ts

```
    testLabelClick() {
    console.log('test works');
  }
```

test.html

```
 <div class="p-col p-col-nogutter p-col-align-center label-text" onclick="testLabelClick()"> {{text}} </div>
```

I'm getting this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testLabelClick is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick
```

Comment: please read Angular documents for events. onclick is for pure js not for angular (click) event is used for angular projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `(click)="testLabelClick()"`

Like this-

```
<div class="p-col p-col-nogutter p-col-align-center label-text" (click)="testLabelClick()"> {{text}} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular event bindings are using brackets, so it should actually be

```html
 <div class="p-col p-col-nogutter p-col-align-center label-text" (click)="testLabelClick()"> 
    {{text}} 
</div>
```

`onclick` is a JavaScript event and would bind to an included script, not to your Angular Component